# Small scale application supporting framework

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I want know about any small scale java/j2ee solution for storing and retrieval  of data from any database using hibernate.

What I'm asking is - Spring/Struts + hibernate is being used for mid level application development. 
Even for very small scale application development we know that JDBC and servlet/JSP  is always a bad idea.

Is there any framework that support for example 10 different pages of data representation and possibly 10 tables to store data?
{not willing to do it with php - that is possibly the best alternative}

Can I use spring+hibernate for such  small scale application ?

Comment: Sure, why not? If you'll already be using spring, it'd probably be worth using spring-mvc instead of struts, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Spring+Hibernate to you, may be you think the combination is a overkill for your project, but have my world, always do the best you can in design and development (even for a small project), so many small projects will become big ones.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC and hibernate are good fit for your requirement.

I personally feel these two are enough for small scale applications.

Even though you add new screens in future,they are very flexible.

Comment: I went the wicket way - I find it very flexible as you can access directly your html. 
Wicket, Spring, Hibernate is my solution - I'm quite happy with it so far

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good idea, Spring MVC/Hibernate... I also like VRaptor/Hibernate...
The Spring framework is designed for simple or complex applications, this is an alternative for the complicated EJB solution...
The Hibernate framework is a good and powerful tool, but is a little bit complex and heavy weight... I don't know about your application, but if you want/need a lightweight solution I think there is an alternative for this... The only alternative that I know is the iBatis (the name was changed, but I don't remember the new one)... This may be a good one...

Comment: The name is changed to **MyBatis**, iBatis was hosted on apache.org but MyBatis is hosted on Google codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grails, http://grails.org/. It's built on top of spring and hibernate, but most of the boilerplate code has been eliminated by the grails framework.