# Is Hibernate suitable for a small web application?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm

I'm designing a small JavaEE web application... I have a PostgreSQL database with nearly 10 tables..... I have Activiti handling Workflow....

I thought Spring MVC and hibernate are good fit for my requirement.

But some one asked, **is Hibernate suitable for my use case? Is it too heavy**? How to choose that which ORM would be feasible for a web application?

Feel free to also suggest better solution :)
Thanks

----UPDATE---------

1. The application of course will grow and add more tables in the future.
2. I won't use DDD.

Comment: Why would it be too heavy - did they suggest a reason?

Comment: Hard to tell. Can your servers handle that extra load Hibernate could generate? Is this application expected to grow in the future? Are your developers more used to Hibernate than to plain JDBC?

Comment: They said Hibernate is heavyweight ORMapping and very difficult to maintain - For a small web application with 10 tables only.

Comment: Any lightweight ORM suggestion that can work harmoniously with Sping MVC?

Comment: @orique, could you explain "Can your servers handle that extra load Hibernate could generate?". Is it meant "Hibernate will cost extra high overload?"

Comment: Of course, the application will grow and add more tables in the future.

Comment: Hibernate will ofcourse impact on your memory with taking some PERMGEN space for reflection purposes. But with time hibernate has matured into a very robust framework. In my opinion it would generate much cleaner SQL compared to any that an average person with SQL knowledge will be able to write. That being said, if you still want to go lightweight i would suggest using Spring's JDBCTemplate and map your data using DTO mappers.

Comment: I mean, Hibernate in the end is a set of libraries, so it will consume a bit more RAM, more disk, and so on. Personally I don't think it's a big issue, but that depends on your constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief:
**No**

But also perhaps...

Hibernate is useful if it is a new project without a database a schema to jam into hibernate. It allows to abstract the database away and think in terms of objects. And get you up an running quickly. However it seems your project is already up and running so these benefits are void.

Hibernate is mostly in the way when the project grows, especially if the schema grows. 
Hibernate is not helpful if you intend to go DDD and heavy domain objects as Hibernate prefers dumb pojo domain models.

If you already know you will stay with PostgreSQL then ORMs benefit of being database provider agnostic is pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you address more on why Hibernate is more useful if it is a new project than reverse engineering from database tables? (I also updated the question.)

Answer (score 2):

It helps reduce the lines of code, makes system more understandable .You can concentrate more on  business logic rather than persistence work (SQLs). More important, a system with less code is more easier to refactor.

```
Of course, the application will grow and add more tables in the future.
```

Then it wont become an small application .

[Small scale application supporting framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386286/small-scale-application-supporting-framework)

Comment: And its not that much heavy